# Express/Passport Authentication with a remote SPA? Where is the cookie?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, session-cookies, passport-local

OK, I give up.

I'm trying to build a passport-local authentication, but I want to do it with an SPA. I've done it before with server side rendering, but I want to do it with a completely separate app. So, I have a server running on 8080 and an SPA (made with CRA) running on 3000.

I've managed to get it to work with JWTs, but now I want to go back and see if I can do it with session/cookies. As I understand it (correct me if I'm wrong), the server creates a session when the user logs in, and that gets saved as a cookie on the client that gets sent back to the server in future requests.

In my server I have:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const favicon = require('serve-favicon');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const cors = require('cors')

// ...

var app = express();

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(cors({ origin: 'http://localhost:3000' }))
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(require('express-session')({
  cookie: { httpOnly: false },
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


app.use('/auth', auth);
app.use('/data', data);

// passport config
var Account = require('./models/account');
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(Account.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(Account.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(Account.deserializeUser());
```

and in my routes I have:

```
router.post('/register', (req, res, next) => {
  Account.register(new Account({ username : req.body.username }), req.body.password, (err, account) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(201).json({ error : err.message });
    }

    passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, () => {
      req.session.save((err) => {
        if (err) {
          return next(err);
        }
        res.status(200).json({ msg: "registered", user: account });
      });
    });
  });
});

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), (req, res, next) => {
  req.session.save((err) => {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    console.log('req.session', req.session)
    console.log('req.user', req.user)
    res.session = { cookie: req.session.cookie }
    res.cookie('userid', req.user._id, { maxAge: 2592000000 });
    res.status(200).json({ msg: "logged in", user: req.user });
  });
});

router.get('/logout', (req, res, next) => {
  req.logout();
  req.session.save((err) => {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    res.status(200).json({ msg: "logged out" });
  });
});

router.get("/unprotected", (req, res) => {
  console.log('\n\n**** req.cookies', req.cookies, '\n\n')
  console.log('\n\n**** req.session', req.session, '\n\n')
  res.json({ data: "Anyone can see uprotected route." })
})

function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated())
    return next();
  res.sendStatus(401);
}

router.get('/protected', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
  console.log('in auth')
  res.json({ data: "Success! This is the protected data!" })
});
```

As I understand it, what I want is a cookie to show up on the client. A couple times I've found a cookie called *connect.sid* but I couldn't get it to do it repeatably (I probably changed something before I realized it was working.) Presumably I should see it in Postman as well.

When I try to access this route from the client, I've gone through a couple of versions, but I'm currently doing for register:

```
handleRegister(userData) {
  fetch(
    AUTH_REGISTER_URL,
    {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(userData),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }
    }
  )
  .then((response) => {
    if (response.status === 200) {
      return response.json()
    }
    return null
  })
  .then((json) => {
    if (json.user) {
      this.setState({ userData: json.user })
    } else {
      console.error('login failed')
    }
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error('error logging in', err)
  })
}
```

and this is how I'm trying to access the protected data route:

```
fetch(DATA_PROTECTED_URL, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  }
})
.then((response) => {
  if (response.status === 200)
    return response.json()
  return null
})
.then((json) => {
  console.log('json', json)
  if (json)
    this.setState({ dataProtected: json })
  else
    this.setState({ dataProtected: { data: "What? No JSON data sent." } })
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.error('error fetching protected data', err)
})
```

These are the routes I'm using in the client:

```
const SERVER_URL = "http://localhost:8080"

export const AUTH_REGISTER_URL = SERVER_URL     + '/auth/register'
export const AUTH_LOGIN_URL = SERVER_URL        + '/auth/login'
export const AUTH_LOGOUT_URL = SERVER_URL       + '/auth/logout'

export const DATA_PROTECTED_URL = SERVER_URL    + '/auth/protected'
export const DATA_UNPROTECTED_URL = SERVER_URL  + '/auth/unprotected'
```

Note: There are also */data/protected* and */data/unprotected* on the server, but I'm working out of the *auth.js* file for ease.

So, what am I not getting? What am I getting wrong?

The code is [here](https://github.com/kevinsmithwebdev/ppl). Please note that there may still be some leftover code from when I was doing this with JWTs - I'm trying to get the basic routes to work before changing everything else.

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're including `credentials: include` for all your protected requests. So, it'll look like:

```
fetch(url, {
  headers: // stuff
  credentials: 'include',
  body: // stuff
})
```

Comment: OK, that has helped a bunch. I had `credentials: 'include'` in  some of the fetch calls, but had mistakenly included it in the headers. I also had to put `credentials: true` in my *cors* middleware on the server. And I had to put the `credentials: 'include'` in the login and register fetches to get the cookie returned on this. Thanks.